# undef is not of type Gtk2::Gdk::Drawable - gtk2-perl custom widget - calling window method of a GtkWidget

Tags: gtk, gtk2

I'm trying to make a custom Perl Gtk2 widget. When I try to access the `window` property of the GtkDrawingArea, it returns `undef` rather than a `GdkDrawable` object. According to [the Gtk2-Perl documentation](http://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net/doc/pod/Gtk2/Widget.html#window_or_undef_widg1) this method can return either the window object or `undef`, but it isn't clear under what conditions it returns `undef`. Could someone please clarify this?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package Gtk2::MIDIPlot;

use Gtk2;
use base 'Gtk2::DrawingArea';
use Cairo;

sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my $this = bless Gtk2::DrawingArea->new(), $class;

  $this->set_size_request(14400, 768);

  return $this;
}

sub draw {
  my $drawArea = shift;

  my $thisCairoSurface = Gtk2::Gdk::Cairo::Context->create($drawArea->window);
}

package main;

use Gtk2 -init;

my $window = Gtk2::Window->new();

my $mainWidgetScroll = Gtk2::ScrolledWindow->new();
my $mainWidget = Gtk2::MIDIPlot->new();
$mainWidget->draw($mainWidget);
$mainWidgetScroll->add_with_viewport($mainWidget);
$mainWindow->add($mainWidgetScroll);

$window->signal_connect(destroy => sub{Gtk2->main_quit()});
$window->show_all();
Gtk2->main();

0;
```

Comment: It will return `undef` when the widget has not been "realized". Realization is the act of associating a GdkWindow to a GtkWidget; unrealization is the reverse. You will need to look up how to properly draw with cairo on GTK+ 2, and translate the algorithm to Perl. (I believe it has to do with the `expose` signal...) Alternatively, you can use GTK+ 3, where each widget has a `draw` signal that provides its own cairo context that you can connect to to do your own custom drawing.

Comment: Thanks @andlabs. I posted my solution below. I had to connect my draw function to the expose signal so as to give time for the window to be created. I actually had looked at the example linked in my answer to figure this out, but thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [this example](http://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net/doc/examples/histogramplot.pl.html) I discovered I need to wait for the expose event of the widget before being able to draw on it, as the window has not been created until that event. Also, the code needs to fit better with the GTK style of setting things up, then executing actions in callbacks.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package Gtk2::MIDIPlot;

use Gtk2;
use base 'Gtk2::DrawingArea';
use Cairo;

sub new {
  my $class = shift;
  my $this = bless Gtk2::DrawingArea->new(), $class;

  $this->signal_connect(expose_event => 'Gtk2::MIDIPlot::draw');

  return $this;
}

sub draw {
  my $drawArea = shift;

  $drawArea->set_size_request(14400, 768);
  my $thisCairoSurface = Gtk2::Gdk::Cairo::Context->create($drawArea->get_window());
}
```